# How can I send email through python script when my company email is hosted on Google

Tags: python, email, gmail, email-attachments, google-workspace

Just like many big companies using Office365, my company is using google (gsuite) to host their email domain. I need to send automated emails to multiple people within organisation using a python script. How can that be done?

Comment: Do you care what the `From:` address is on these emails?

Comment: gmail has SMTP much like Outlook, so it's just a matter of using the right SMTP server.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a 3rd party service like [Mailgun](http://mailgun.com), it provides a REST API which if you hit you can trigger emails that it will send from a custom domain you configure on the service.

Its super easy to use for python, I use it for Raspberry Pi projects.

```
def send_simple_message():
    return requests.post(
        "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/messages",
        auth=("api", "YOUR_API_KEY"),
        data={"from": "Excited User <mailgun@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME>",
            "to": ["bar@example.com", "YOU@YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME"],
            "subject": "Hello",
            "text": "Testing some Mailgun awesomness!"})
```

It is a nice alternative to using a corporate SMTP server.

Comment: Using unapproved third part services to send company emails is just asking for trouble.

Comment: @r.ook Definitely a valid comment, depends on the usage. If they are sending reports or internal use only information a definite no no. An alert email for a failing build or triggered alarm system maybe not so important. Probably best to ask whoever is in charge!

Answer (score 0):

Got it fixed.

In order to send an email from Python, we first need to switch ON "Less secure app access" https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps?utm_source=google-account&utm_medium=web.

This we need to do if we don't have 2 Factor Authentication.

If you use 2 Factor Authentication, then you need to create an App Password and use that particular password while sending an email and not your regular password.

To create an App Password use this link: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/185833?hl=en

Now using sample script like below, we can send an email.

```
import smtplib

# creates SMTP session
s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)

# start TLS for security
s.starttls()

# Authentication
s.login("username@domain.com", "app_password")

# message to be sent
message = "Message_you_need_to_send"

# sending the mail
s.sendmail("username@domain.com", "recipient@domain.com", message)

# terminating the session
s.quit()
```

Comment: This no longer works in 2022

Answer (score 0):

Google provides Gmail api suite for python and it is the preferred way to access versus smtp login/password

You should refer to their [developer console](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python) for examples and tutorials